# Can't find R. layout - app name. Only android layout

Tags: java, android

For some reason, when i started up eclipse today, it couldn't find my main XML in my

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

When i write R. it can only find "Layout - Android.R" - and not my "Layout - com.your.app"

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

**I just realised my Java file in the /gen folder is missing, how do i retrieve it again?**

**Cleaning project doesn't work**

Comment: Do cleanup and build again.  That should resolve the issue.

Comment: Try manually deleting the gen folder...it works...

Comment: see if you have the following line: import android.R;  , replace it with import your.project.package.R;

Comment: If you have errors in your resource files, R.java won't be generated. Check the Problems view (Window -> Show View -> Problems).

Answer (score 20):

You need to remove the import android.R statement at the top of the file.

See here for more information:
http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Comment: That did it for me! Since this wa a project imported from Eclipse, I had totally forgotten that Eclipse explicitely imports R. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Try Right click on project > android tools > Fix Project properties
2. Project > Clean
3. Project > Build Project

Answer (score 2):

- Option 1)`Project` > `Android Tools` > `Fix Project Properties`.
  Clean and Rebuild your project.
- Option 2) Refresh your project <kbd>F5</kbd>, Delete folders `/gen` and `/bin` then Rebuild your project
- Option 3) update the `build tools`, some time this will cause a lot of problems and you will have the annoying message related to "Can't find R.layout"

But in this case you wil fix, delete because you don´t need this:

```
import android.R;
```

i think this is your problem.

Folder `/gen` is automatically generated, but you will solve problems related to resources, probably something missing in your layouts, one of them will have a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

check you are importing the current `R` class, and enable `Auto Build` under `project` menu, if enabled, then use `clean` under the same menu to rebuild the `R` class

Comment: Neither of it helps, also i can't Import com.yourpackage.R; It just asks if i want to create a new class. However, i just realised that my Java file in the gen folder is missing for some unknown reason - might be because of that? Any way to retrieve it again?

Comment: yeah u can retrieve it by calling clean

Comment: mm, try right click on your project, select android tools --> fix project properties, then clean

Comment: Nevermind, it appeeared now, for some unknown reason - Thank you

Comment: and try to update the sdk, go to help menu select check for updates

Comment: This was what I looked for. "android.R.layout" is actually different from "R.layout"... the first contains standard-layouts, the second your layouts. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

It can be that your project contains errors. To see list of resources it must be able to compile. After that your resources will apear.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with one of my project where I copied an existing XML file (say xmlfile) over.
Then, Java file cannot resolve R.layout.xmlfile.

I guess it is probably due to the end of line feed/CR compatibility between Windows and Linux.
so, I pruned all the LF/CR and re-saved it on my Mac machine.
Then, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi had same problem few minute ago. I kept looking and looking and finally i found out -- >

Its because i was using a file in drawable folder with

1-launch-screen.jpg (Invalid Name for drawable file)

Make sure your file name has valid.

> It can not have any '-' character in drawable filename.
>   File name has to be all small letters only.

And that red X mark automatically disappeared and project started top built and i was able to see R.layout.MyNewLayout.

Hope this helps !